# How to compile when the machine has not enough memory?

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation, vps, irc

I have a low-end VPS that is set up with a ZNC as an IRC bouncer, and it runs just fine, it has around 128 MB of flash memory, which is NOT ENOUGH to compile one of the modules I want to use [`znc-push`](https://github.com/jreese/znc-push) .

After trying to compile on a virtualbox and sending the file over, I get an error of "invalid ELF header" when I try to load the module up. How can I compile this module remotely and then send it over? It has enough memory to run it, but won't compile it, I've looked in to using distcc, but I can't find any reliable info on how to use it.

Also, I have tried creating a swap file, but that's not allowed/possible with this VPS.

Comment: How well did you copy the arch and version of software running on the VPS in the virtualbox image?

Comment: The virtualbox setup is a debian 7 netinstall image, the VPS is an OpenVZ debian 7 minimal install, the versions of software are all the same, but the architecture might be what's causing problems.

Comment: @Kam So what are the architectures involved? Chances are that you built a 64-bit executable but the VPS is a 32-bit system. But *you* need to check and tell us.

Comment: They were definitely both 32 bit architectures for debian. I switched over from a debian image to ubuntu and the compilation from a VM worked just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously such machine has no resources, and is not intended for development purposes.

For such tasks, you cannot compile blindly in the native architecture of your (Intel) Debian, that is clearly an alien architecture/binaries to your small server.

You need to build a cross-compiler (cross)toolchain in a remote machine/in your Debian 7, that compiles sources generating binaries for the target architecture.

Usually the cross toolchain may have specific steps to install, and might need some tweaks for your environment.

> A cross compiler is a compiler capable of creating executable code for
>   a platform other than the one on which the compiler is running.
>
> A cross compiler is necessary to compile for multiple platforms from
>   one machine. A platform could be infeasible for a compiler to run on,
>   such as for the microcontroller of an embedded system because those
>   systems contain no operating system.

As an example,

[How to Build a GCC Cross-Compiler](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/)

As another example, I once also setup up a cross compiler in Debian for NetBSD/ARM ; or for instance, if I need binaries for my openwrt/32-bit MIPS, I have to get the cross-compiling environment that matches uClib and 32-bit MIPS - my MIPs based router only has 96MB of RAM, and 128MB (or 256MB?) of flash.

Talking about that, some embedded/small router environment use [uClib](https://www.uclibc.org) instead of glibc to save space, as uClib is so much more smaller than glibc.

> uClibc is a small C standard library
>   intended for Linux kernel-based operating systems for embedded systems
>   and mobile devices.
>
> uClibc was mostly
>   written from scratch,but has incorporated code from glibc and
>   other projects.
>
> uClibc is a wrapper around the system calls of the Linux kernel and
>   μClinux. uClibc is much smaller than the glibc, the C library normally
>   used with Linux distributions. While glibc is intended to fully
>   support all relevant C standards across a wide range of hardware and
>   kernel platforms, uClibc is specifically focused on embedded Linux.
>   Features can be enabled or disabled according to space requirements.

Often you also have [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) replacing and giving you a bare down version of the binary utils you have in a linux e.g. you will notice `ls` and `find`, for instance, are different, less powerful and have less options to use.

> BusyBox is software that provides several stripped-down Unix tools in
>   a single executable file. It runs in a variety of POSIX environments
>   such as Linux, Android,[7] and FreeBSD,[8] although many of the tools
>   it provides are designed to work with interfaces provided by the Linux
>   kernel. It was specifically created for embedded operating systems
>   with very limited resources.

The differences also not end up here. Instead of Apache, you might have got Luci; and instead of OpenSSH, [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) SSH.

> Dropbear is a relatively small SSH server and client. Dropbear is
>   particularly useful for "embedded"-type Linux (or other Unix) systems,
>   such as wireless routers.

You will also have a very stripped down Linux kernel, and not necessarily the latest version. In some Chinese boards, it may also be somewhat "hacked" to support non-standard hardware, and you (and often the vendor) won't be able to recompile it for newer versions.

I am afraid you will have to research a little bit more about your small machine environment; I also hope this answer will help you realise it is not expected to handle an embedded Linux in all ways you deal with a full fledged Linux server.

As always, besides having the tools, it is necessary to understand them.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work just to run one make command. :/ it's not an embedded environment though, it's a OpenVZ virtual environment running Debian, which is why I thought it would be easiest to compile on a different VM with the same version of debian and send the files back to the VPS.

Comment: Most probably 32 bits then....the bit about Dropbear and busybox might apply, who knows about uClib.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough storage space, you can extend RAM by swap.

For Ubuntu:

1. `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile && sudo chmod 600 /swapfile && sudo
   mkswap /swapfile && sudo swapon /swapfile && sudo nano /etc/fstab`
2. Then manually add following line to /etc/fstab : `/swapfile   none    swap 
   sw    0   0`
3. reboot

Compile with no RAM errors. Good luck!